# Calling multiple viewmodel methods from launchWhenStarted does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

This code invokes two methods on the same viewmodel and listens for updates. But only the first method completes, the second does not event trigger.

```
private fun initData() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.incrementCount().collect {
            info { "Count: $it" }
        }

        viewModel.getAllTeams().collect {
            when (it) {
                is State.Success -> {
                    info { "Got teams with size: ${it.result}.size" }
                }
                is State.Error -> {
                    info { "Error getting teams: ${it.message}" }
                }
                State.Loading -> {
                    info { "Loading all teams" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel(), com.droid.common.Logger {

fun incrementCount(): MutableStateFlow<Int> {
    val countState = MutableStateFlow(0)

    viewModelScope.launch {
        repeat(5) {
            countState.value = (it)
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    return countState
}

fun getAllTeams(): MutableStateFlow<State> {
    val state = MutableStateFlow<State>(State.None)

    state.value = State.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val allTeams = FootballAPIClient.apiService.getAllTeams()
            state.value = State.Success(allTeams)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            error { "Error getting all teams: ${exception.message}" }
            state.value = State.Error(exception.message.toString())
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

However, calling them with separate lifecycleScope works

```
private fun initData() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.incrementCount().collect {
            info { "Count: $it" }
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.getAllTeams().collect {
            when (it) {
                is State.Success -> {
                    info { "Got teams with size: ${it.result}.size" }
                }
                is State.Error -> {
                    info { "Error getting teams: ${it.message}" }
                }
                State.Loading -> {
                    info { "Loading all teams" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to understand this behavior, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You will need different coroutines, since `collect()` is a suspending function that suspends until your `Flow` terminates.

The problem with `launchWhenStarted` is that while your newly emitted items will not be processed your producer will still run in the background.

For collecting multiple flows the currently recommended way is:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch {
          viewModel.incrementCount().collect { ... }   
        }
    
        launch {
            viewModel.getAllTeams().collect { ... }
        }
    }
}
```